# Core Data NSManagedObject isFault inside prepareForDeletion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm doing some processing inside `- prepareForDeletion` in a `NSManagedObject`. However when I try to access some properties of this class they are returned to me as `nil` (even though I know they are not `nil`). So I check if my object is fault `[self isFault]` and it returns `YES`.

So how can I make the object "not fault" when I'm inside `- prepareForDeletion` because I need to access a property?

**PhoneGroup.m (NSManagedObject)**

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion {

    [super prepareForDeletion];

    NSArray *individuals = [self.individuals allObjects]; // individuals is nil

    for (int i = 0; i < [individuals count]; i++) {

        Individual *individual = [individuals objectAtIndex:i];

        BOOL individualExistsInOtherGroups = [individual.phoneGroups count] > 1;

        BOOL individualAddedAsAdditionalContactToReminder = [individual.reminders count] > 0;

        // We can delete the individual if individual does not exist in other groups and is not added to any reminders

        if (!individualExistsInOtherGroups && !individualAddedAsAdditionalContactToReminder && ![individual isDeleted]) {

            [[CoreDataHelper sharedInstance] deleteEntity:individual inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        }
    }

    // Post a notification to notify all interested VC so they can refresh the GUI
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:RMContactDeletedNotification object:self];
    DLog(@"Contact deleted notification sent");
}
```

**Model information:**

`PhoneGroup` has an inverse to-many relationship to `Individual` with delete rule nullify.

`Individual` has an inverse to-many relationship to `PhoneGroup` with delete rule nullify.

`Contact` is a superclass for `Individual`s and `PhoneGroup`s

Here's an image to visualize better.

[image]

### EDIT: I have made some more findings on this issue

`PhoneGroup` only seems to fault when there is a relationship to a `Reminder`. If a `PhoneGroup` does not have a relationship to a `Reminder` when it is being deleted it is **not** fault.

`Reminder` has an optional inverse to-many relationship to `Contact` with delete rule nullify.

`Contact` has an optional inverse to-many relationship to `Reminder` with delete rule nullify.

What gives of this?

### EDIT 2: More findins on the issue

I tried Dan Shelly's alternative solution to do a fetch of `Individual`s **however** even the `self.managedObjectContext` of the `NSManagedObject` (`PhoneGroup`) is `nil` inside `- prepareForDeletion` what does this imply?

Comment: The code for the processes!

Comment: Please, show some details about your model and the delete rules for relationships.

Comment: @Sulthan I added information about database model

Comment: Could you try `for (Individual* individual in self.individuals)`? I have doubts about calling `allObject` on the fault relationship.

Comment: Do you retain managedObjectContext which is used to retrieve the object somewhere? Maybe it is released already and your object becames fault and properties are nil. (i've run into this once, self.managedObjectContext is not strong reference)

Comment: @Sulthan I tried doing `for (Individual* individual in self.individuals)` but it will just end the loop immediately since self.individuals is `nil`

Comment: @Mindaugas Yes the MOC is retained...

Comment: so `self.managedObjectContext` is not `nil` , right?

Comment: Are you invoking `prepareForDeletion` manually?

Comment: Nope. I will try Idz advice to call super prepareForDeletion at a later stage...

Answer (score 1):

> > Why does `[self.individuals allObjects]` return nil?

**Edit:**
After discovering that your `managedObjectContext` is `nil` it is safe to say that your object has been disowned by its context.
This might be caused by a context `reset` or deallocation, while you maintain a strong reference to your object.
However this won't explain how this happen inside the `prepareForDeletion` method.
This method is invoked when a live context is deleting an object (`[context deleteObject:...]`).
This would mean that either you invoke `prepareForDeletion` manually (`[object prepareForDeletion]`), or that another thread is reseting/deallocating your context in mid-delete.

> > Note: The below code will work given that you have a valid `objectID` and a live `managedObjectContext` set on your object.

**However**, I might have a work around as the way you access your data is somewhat inefficient (will explain shortly):

If your deleted object (`PhoneGroup`) `individuals` relationship is not faulted, CoreData will forst access the store to fault the relationship (1st trip). you will then have faults as objects contained in that relationship (N objects), your loop will access them one by one (N trips to the store). still in the loop, you access each object for its relationships (2 relations ships, `phoneGroups` and `reminders` ==> 2 trips to the store PER ITEM).
In conclusion: 1 + N + 2*N = 3*N +1 trips to the store (worst case).

This could be accomplished in a much simpler way:
* create this fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest* r = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Individual"];
[r setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN phoneGroups AND phoneGroups.@count == 1 AND reminders.@count == 0",[self objectID]]];
[r setIncludesPropertyValues:YES];
[r setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[r setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];
```

* now all that is left is:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSArray* individuals = [context executeFetchRequest:r error:NULL];    
for (Individual* individual in individuals) {
    [context deleteObject:individual];
}
```

this is accomplished with a single (1) trip to the store in the worst case, and since you don't rely on you relationship directly, this should work as long as your object has its `objectID`.

**Apendix:**

Current implementation performance (SQLite debug):

```
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.700 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM Z_2PHONEGROUPS t1 JOIN ZCONTACT t0 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_2INDIVIDUALS WHERE t1.Z_3PHONEGROUPS = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.701 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.701 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 3 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.715 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "individuals" for objectID 0x8572b70 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/PhoneGroup/p21> fulfilled from database.  Got 3 rows
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.716 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZCONTACTID, t0.ZVISIBLE FROM ZCONTACT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.717 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0005s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.717 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 1 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.718 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x818cad0 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/Individual/p4>
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.718 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM Z_2PHONEGROUPS t1 JOIN ZCONTACT t0 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_3PHONEGROUPS WHERE t1.Z_2INDIVIDUALS = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.719 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.719 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 1 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.719 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "phoneGroups" for objectID 0x818cad0 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/Individual/p4> fulfilled from database.  Got 1 rows
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.720 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZREMINDER t0 WHERE  t0.ZCONTACT = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.721 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0005s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.721 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 0 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.721 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "reminders" for objectID 0x818cad0 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/Individual/p4> fulfilled from database.  Got 0 rows
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.722 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZCONTACTID, t0.ZVISIBLE FROM ZCONTACT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.722 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.722 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 1 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.723 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x818cb90 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/Individual/p16>
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.723 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM Z_2PHONEGROUPS t1 JOIN ZCONTACT t0 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_3PHONEGROUPS WHERE t1.Z_2INDIVIDUALS = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.724 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.724 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 1 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.724 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "phoneGroups" for objectID 0x818cb90 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/Individual/p16> fulfilled from database.  Got 1 rows
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.725 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZREMINDER t0 WHERE  t0.ZCONTACT = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.725 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.726 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 0 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.726 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "reminders" for objectID 0x818cb90 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/Individual/p16> fulfilled from database.  Got 0 rows
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.727 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZCONTACTID, t0.ZVISIBLE FROM ZCONTACT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.727 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.727 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 1 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.728 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x818cba0 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/Individual/p17>
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.728 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM Z_2PHONEGROUPS t1 JOIN ZCONTACT t0 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_3PHONEGROUPS WHERE t1.Z_2INDIVIDUALS = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.729 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.729 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0008s for 4 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.729 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "phoneGroups" for objectID 0x818cba0 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/Individual/p17> fulfilled from database.  Got 4 rows
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.730 P[9666:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZREMINDER t0 WHERE  t0.ZCONTACT = ?
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.730 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0004s
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.731 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0007s for 0 rows.
//2013-05-19 21:34:42.731 P[9666:c07] CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "reminders" for objectID 0x818cba0 <x-coredata://CBE585F2-552D-4FDE-AAEA-2C9C7984FAC9/Individual/p17> fulfilled from database.  Got 0 rows
```

Proposed implementation performance:

```
//2013-05-19 21:13:26.734 P[9609:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME, t0.ZCONTACTID, t0.ZVISIBLE FROM ZCONTACT t0 JOIN Z_2PHONEGROUPS t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_2INDIVIDUALS WHERE ((t1.Z_3PHONEGROUPS = ? AND (SELECT COUNT(t3.Z_3PHONEGROUPS) FROM Z_2PHONEGROUPS t3 WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t3.Z_2INDIVIDUALS) ) = ? AND (SELECT COUNT(t4.Z_PK) FROM ZREMINDER t4 WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t4.ZCONTACT) ) = ?) AND  t0.Z_ENT = ?)
//2013-05-19 21:13:26.735 P[9609:c07] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0008s
//2013-05-19 21:13:26.736 P[9609:c07] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0012s for 2 rows.
```

Data construction (`- (void) synthesizePhoneGroupsAndIndividuals:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context`):

```
NSMutableArray* individuals = [NSMutableArray new];//[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Individual" inManagedObjectContext:context];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < (3 + arc4random() % 100); ++i) {
    Individual* indi = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Individual" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    indi.contactID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cid-%u",i];
    [individuals addObject:indi];
}

NSMutableArray* groups = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 3 + arc4random() % 7; ++i) {
    PhoneGroup* group = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PhoneGroup" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    group.visible = NO;
    NSMutableSet* indis = [group mutableSetValueForKey:@"individuals"];
    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        [indis addObject:[individuals objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % [individuals count])]];
    }
    [groups addObject:group];
}

[context save:NULL];
```

Testing code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
context.persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    [self synthesizePhoneGroupsAndIndividuals:context];
    [context reset];
}];

[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSFetchRequest* r = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"PhoneGroup"];
    NSArray* groups = [context executeFetchRequest:r error:NULL];
    if ([groups count]) {
        PhoneGroup* group = [groups objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % [groups count])];
        [context deleteObject:group];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort in trying to help me. I just added some more information to my issue that possibly can help solve this.

Comment: Please provide a sample code to reproduce this issue, I've extended my test to include reminders, but it did not reproduce even when reminders were attached to the group and the individuals. do you have other `prepareForDeletion` on related objects?

Comment: Hmm it's kind of hard to provide sample code when it's all bundled inside my project. Even though you are not able to reproduce my issue, what options do you have if your `NSManagedObject` subclass is faulting inside `- prepareForDeletion`? `(lldb) p (BOOL) [self isFault] (BOOL) $1 = YES
(BOOL) $1 = YES`

Comment: Could you describe the flow up-to the deletion?

Comment: The flow is that I have `GroupsListViewController` which lists all groups (a fetch is made to retrieve the groups). When I select one of the groups in the list a `GroupDetailsViewController` is pushed on the stack together with the selected group. Then if the user chooses to delete the group in `GroupDetailsViewController` I execute a `[moc deleteObject:group];`

Comment: Hello, I tried your alternative solution to do a fetch of `Individual`s **however** even the `self.managedObjectContext` of the `NSManagedObject` (`PhoneGroup`) is `nil` inside `- prepareForDeletion` what does this imply?

Comment: It means that you have reset your context or it has been deallocated, might be from a different thread, as you would not get into prepare for delete otherwise (unless you call it yourself, and that is not recommended)

Comment: I solved it. Inside `Contact`s `- prepareForDeletion` I was doing a save operation. For some reason doing the save operation caused the `PhoneGroup` to fault so I just commented out the save and it's not faulting anymore. So I suppose lessons learned are that you shouldn't call save inside a `NSManagedObject` ?

Comment: its not 'fault' as much as it is a 'disown', the context has disowned your object (he was deleted and save was committed to the database) and so your object was disowned. don't save in methods that are changing and object as the save should probably be committed/saved after the operation anyway.

Comment: I was following the approach to save "often". Now I was saving too often :P Thanks for helping me out. I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: Thanks, was glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem may be caused by calling `[super prepareForDeletion];` so early. You should probably do the work you want to do **then** call `[super prepareForDeletion];`.

Answer (score 0):

Late in the game, but I just had a few issues similar to that.

Is your store on iCloud?

My problems were related to the fact that I was using coredata with iCloud.
Deleted objects coming from iCloud may already have their properties and related entities no more accessible, even before any call to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`.

I ended up not using any deleted object directly, nor relying on `prepareForDeletion` for accessing the data I needed.

Instead, I cache this information (in user settings is good for my use case), keyed with the objectID. Upon deletion, I retrieve that information using the objectID found in the `NSDeletedObjectsKey` of the notification user info. The cached info is deleted after that.