# What's the point of self.managedObjectContext == nil in NSManagedObject prepareForDeletion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a Reminder entity that needs to update its `date` property whenever a certain entity B is deleted. I've spent some days coding thinking I could do some useful things in my managed object subclass on deletion time. I tried

```
- (void)willSave
{
if (self.isDeleted) 
    // use self.managedObjectContext
}
```

The context was nil. Relationships were also torn down there. Fair enough.

So... I started writing cumbersome code for `prepareForDeletion` to circumvent the fact that the object hadn't been deleted yet, but then Core Data throws self.managedObjectContext == nil in my face. The documentation says that this is where I do stuff "before relationships are torn down". So what is the point in `self.managedObjectContext == nil` if `self.relationshipA.managedObjectContext` is accessible (as the docs suggest)? And more importantly, why does my not yet deleted object not have its context?

I read a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605455/core-data-nsmanagedobject-isfault-inside-preparefordeletion) regarding that problem

> its not 'fault' as much as it is a 'disown', the context has disowned your object (he was deleted and save was committed to the database) and so your object was disowned. don't save in methods that are changing and object as the save should probably be committed/saved after the operation anyway. – Dan Shelly May 21 at 19:05

My code was:

```
[moc deleteObject:obj]
[moc save:NULL]
```

When I removed the save operation my `self.managedObjectContext` existed in `prepareForDeletion`. That is, until auto-save, when it was nil again. Probably because the parent context also deleted it, followed by a save by the UIManagedDocument.

I'm starting to think that my only options are to make a custom delete method (that works until Core Data cascades a deletion, in which case it won't be called), or make a new class that listens to NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification.

**Update:**

[image: My core data model]

The user wants to keep in touch with a person, and wants to be reminded after a certain interval (stored in ContactWish) if no contact has been made. What I'm trying to accomplish is that when the latest ContactOccasion for a certain person is deleted, the corresponding occasion->person->wish->reminder gets updated (using the interval).

Since this is a learning experience for me I wanted to find out the right way (one that works with cascade deletion etc.) and not just call for an update manually from every place in my code where I do `[MOContext deleteObject:occasion]`. Suggestions are welcome.

(the reminder entity has also been prepared for more manual use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be much more logical to have the `Reminder` entity manage its date property? It could "listen" (maybe via `changedValues:`) to its relationship entities being deleted and perform the update.

This seems more consistent, as the `B` entity should not really be concerned with the logic of the `Reminder` entity updates.

**Edit**
Pursuant to the discussion below and based on my opinion that you cannot load up the database cascade delete model too much with update logic:

Rather than react to a deletion you can introduce an attribute that you set and listen to in order to do the changes.

I really do not see how relying on core data delete mechanisms is easier or more elegant than just writing your own "deleteOccasion" method that handles this logic.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and I'm also not comfortable putting reminder logic where it doesn't belong (Right now I have a separate Entity that represents the user's wish to update a Reminder automatically. Preferably the code would be located there). The problem as I see it is that these are managed objects, so I can't really use them to listen in on anything because their life spans aren't managed by me. I can't take for granted that they exist until I explicitly fetch them all and keep a strong reference. What happens (in your case) if the Reminder in question hasn't been fetched yet?

Comment: It will be fetched automatically. I think with the case you describe and my setup you are guaranteed that the objects you want to change are there.

Comment: Okay, I think I don't understand after all ;) Do you mean listening to the `reminder.changedValues` property using KVO? (There are no direct relationships between the Reminder and the B entity) The best I can do is `reminder.person.B` which means I could listen to `reminder.person.changedValues`. Will that really fetch the reminder in question whenever `person.changedValues` is changed?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. There must be a better setup than what you describe.

Comment: I don't know which important parts I left out in my question but feel free to ask about any missing details. Actually I'm describing many things - two failed attempts and two less than desirable solutions. If you know of a third solution I'd be grateful for the help. Or, if someone could help me understand how I can be sure to always have a MOContext in prepareForDeletion then maybe I can solve the problem that way.

Comment: No, I mean there might be a better setup on a higher level. You are trying to ensure data integrity, so maybe your model is not set up well to facilitate that. Post your data model.

Comment: Wilco. I'll try to describe it in new words

Comment: OK - I got it. I think you should *not* delete the contact occasion but simply set an attribute. You can attach your logic to this attribute. The updated reminder in turn can delete the occasion. -- I think you are still stretching the model. That is not what cascading is meant for. This is fairly complicated logic, much more than just deleting or nullifying child entities. In my experience the appropriate design pattern is to handle this in a controller.

Comment: Ah, is this right?: You advise against relying on core data deletion mechanisms for this kind of database update. Your solution will solve the issues with the missing managed object context in prepareForDeletion, "losing" a Reminder update because Core Data didn't deliver a notification, as well as having to update the Reminder in a separate step. From what I understand it will not, however, uncouple ContactOccasion from Reminder, and will not work with regular deleteObject: calls. Then, if I got it right, it would be equally effective as a custom [contactOccasion deleteOccasion] method.

Comment: (Assuming that by "attribute" you don't mean a relationship between ContactOccasion and Reminder for this purpose only -- but if you did then I see how the Reminder logic would move to its right place as a consequence)

Comment: I edited my answer to summarize this. I would go with a custom method.